# Parameter names in abstract tupled function

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

Related to [No argument names in abstract declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487551/no-argument-names-in-abstract-declaration), how would you do this with a C#-style tupled argument?  So if I wanted

```
abstract member createEmployee : (string * string) -> Employee
```

how would I be able to communicate whether it should be

```
1-   member this.createEmployee(firstName, lastName) = ...
2-   member this.createEmployee(lastName, firstName) = ...
```

Use case: creating an interface in F# to be used from C#.

Comment: Communicate? XML comments, just as with C# or VB.Net. Enforce? No idea...

Comment: Maybe some sort of hack with units of measure?

Comment: @ildjarn wouldn't really work if it's compiled into a DLL to use from C#.

Comment: @Dax : Edited my comment per your edit.

Comment: @JohnPalmer would there be any way to use that from C#?

Comment: @DaxFohl - I don't think so

Comment: you can use phantom-types to simulate unit-of-messure like behavior (without the *calculation* part) - so maybe this might be an idea? Or you simply create new types like `type FirstName = FirstName of string`... so you'll get totally typesafe

Comment: @ildjarn the xml comment seems to get overridden; it still appears as obj1, obj2 from c# in intellisense.

Comment: @Carsten, apparently UoM for strings [do not work very well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417150/compile-time-constraints-for-strings-in-f-similar-to-units-of-measure-is-it), I'm "fighting" with those for three years, still no luck :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
abstract createEmployee: firstName:string * lastName:string -> Employee
```

compiles to create C# invocation semantics and the names appear both in C# and F# intellisense in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: but this will give you no guarantees from the compiler that the user of your function does not mess up the order at all :) - but hey if it works for you ;)

Comment: @Carsten I see the advantage of your solution and would go with it if I were starting from scratch, but being in the middle of a big old project with compatibility concerns, this seems to be the pragmatic short-term solution.

Comment: hey no problem - whatever works (and as long as you have **FUN**) ;)

Comment: @Carsten Having *much* more fun now that I'm able to clear out the doSomething.Invoke(firstArg).Invoke(second).Invoke(third) etc from my c# code.  Thanks for the pointer on not parenthesizing the args; the difference is very pronounced when calling from C#.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way is to go like this:

```
type FirstName = FirstName of string
type LastName  = LastName of string

...

abstract member createEmployee : (FirstName * LastName) -> Employee
```

### remark:

you probably want it to be

```
abstract member createEmployee : FirstName * LastName -> Employee
```

instead as there are slight differences ;)

Comment: Offhand, do you know if Json.net will serialize/deserialize those types as regular strings, or does it add extra stuff during serialization?  Need to maintain api compatibility.

Comment: well no it will most likely have problems with that - I usually define DTOs if I have problem with this kind of stuff - sorry did not know you need it to work with serializers - want me to remove the answer?

Comment: So to extract the string would I have to do a `match` each time or is there a shortcut?

Comment: the usual shortcut is to deconstruct/pattern-match where you need it - for example `let myFun (FirstName fn) = ...` in F#, you don't really have to use `match` here as it's the only possibitie anyway - and you can add `member` function/properties to it as well if you like

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do that:

1. Use Named Arguments as described in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx)

   ```
   member this.createEmployee(firstName: string, lastName: string) = ...

   // external code
   MyClass.createEmployee(firstName = "John", lastName = "Smith")
   MyClass.createEmployee(lastName = "Smith", firstName = "John")
   ```
2. Make your class member accept a structure as an argument:

   ```
   type EmployeeName =
      struct 
         val firstName: string
         val lastName: string
      end 

   member this.createEmployee2(employeeName: EmployeeName) = ...

   // external code
   MyClass.createEmployee2 {firstName = "John"; lastName = "Smith"}
   MyClass.createEmployee2 {lastName = "Smith"; firstName = "John"}
   ```

The choice is yours; the former allows for optional arguments (consider `middleName` or `salutation`) while the latter allows for storing the structure together (e.g. if you need to process it further).